# Extending CsvBulkloader and ModelAdmin Class in Silverstripe 4

Tags: php, silverstripe, silverstripe-4

I am looking to extend Silverstripe's CSVBulkLoader class to do some business logic before/upon import.

---

In the **WineAdmin Class** (extending ModelAdmin), I have a custom loader defined with **$model_importers** property:

```
//WineAdmin.php
private static $model_importers = [
  'Wine' => 'WineCsvBulkLoader'
];
```

In the **WineCsvBulkLoader** Class, the **$columnMap** property maps CSV columns to SS DataObject columns:

```
//WineCsvBulkLoader.php
use SilverStripe\Dev\CsvBulkLoader;

class WineCsvBulkLoader extends CsvBulkLoader 
{
   public $columnMap = [
        // csv columns              // SS DO columns
        'Item Number'               => 'ItemNumber',
        'COUNTRY'                   => 'Country',
        'Producer'                  => 'Producer',
        'BrandName'                 => 'BrandName',
         // etc
   ];
```

- *When the import is run, the WineCsvBulkLoader class is being invoked, but, the column mappings do not seem to work properly, returning values only where the [key] and [value] in the array are identical. Otherwise, the imported columns are empty. What could be causing this?*

Additionally, the **$duplicateChecks** property is set to look for duplicates.

```
   public $duplicateChecks = [
     'ItemNumber' => 'ItemNumber'
   ];

}
```

- *What does the $duplicateChecks property actually do when there is a duplicate? Does it skip the record?*
- *Can I use callbacks here?*

---

In the [docs](https://docs.silverstripe.org/en/4/developer_guides/integration/csv_import/), I found some code for an example method that splits data in a column into 2 parts and maps those parts to separate columns on the class:

```
public static function importFirstAndLastName(&$obj, $val, $record) 
{
   $parts = explode(' ', $val);
   if(count($parts) != 2) return false;
   $obj->FirstName = $parts[0];
   $obj->LastName = $parts[1];
}
```

- *Is $obj the final import object? How does it get processed?*
- *$val seems to be the value of the column in the csv being imported. Is that correct?*
- *What is contained in $record?*

---

Here are some additional enhancements I hope to make:

- Read the Byte Order Marker, if present, upon import, and do something useful with it
- Upon import, check for duplicate records, and if there are duplicates, I’d like to only update the columns in the record that have changed.
- Delete records that are already in the database, that are not in the CSV being imported
- Add whatever security measures are necessary to use this custom class securely.
- Export CSV with BOM (byte order mark as UTF8)

I'm not looking for a complete answer, but appreciative of any insights.

Comment: $columnMap seems to be getting bypassed, even though my WineCsvBulkLoader class is being invoked and I have defined $columnMap with the pertinent details. When I do the import, the mappings aren't working. what might be causing this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'll attempt to answer some of your questions based on SilverStripe 4.2.0:

Judging by the logic in `CsvBulkLoader::findExistingObject` the duplicateChecks property is used to help finding an existing record in order to update it (rather than create it). It will use defined values in the array in order to find the *first* record that matches a given value and return it.

> What does the `$duplicateChecks` property actually do when there is a duplicate? Does it skip the record?

Nothing, it will just return the first record it finds.

> Can I use callbacks here?

Kind of. You can use a method on the instance of CsvBulkLoader, but you can't pass it a callback directly (e.g. from _config.php etc). Example:

```
public $duplicateChecks = [
    'YourFieldName' => [
        'callback' => 'loadRecordByMyFieldName'
    ]
];

/**
 * Take responsibility for loading a record based on "MyFieldName" property
 * given the CSV value for "MyFieldName" and the original array record for the row
 *
 * @return DataObject|false
 */
public function loadRecordByMyFieldName($inputFieldName, array $record)
{
    // ....
```

**Note:** duplicateChecks callbacks are not currently covered by unit tests. There's a todo in CsvBulkLoaderTest to add them.

> Is `$obj` the final import object? How does it get processed?

You can see where these magic-ish methods get called in `CsvBulkLoader::processRecord`:

```
if ($mapped && strpos($this->columnMap[$fieldName], '->') === 0) {
    $funcName = substr($this->columnMap[$fieldName], 2);
    $this->$funcName($obj, $val, $record);    // <-------- here: option 1
} elseif ($obj->hasMethod("import{$fieldName}")) {
    $obj->{"import{$fieldName}"}($val, $record); // <----- here: option 2
} else {
    $obj->update(array($fieldName => $val));
}
```

This is actually a little misleading, especially because the method's PHPDoc says "Note that columnMap isn't used." Nevertheless, the priority will be given to a value in the `columnMap` property being `->myMethodName`. In both the documentation you linked to and the `CustomLoader` test implementation in the framework's unit tests, they both use this syntax to specifically target the handler for that column:

```
$loader->columnMap = array(
    'FirstName' => '->importFirstName',
```

In this case, `$obj` is the DataObject that you're going to update (e.g. a `Member`).

If you don't do that, you can define `importFirstName` on the DataObject that's being imported, and the `elseif` in the code above will then call that function. In that case the `$obj` is not provided because you can use `$this` instead.

"Is it the final import object" - yes. It gets written after the loop that code is in:

```
// write record
if (!$preview) {
    $obj->write();
}
```

Your custom functions would be required to set the data to the `$obj` (or `$this` if using `importFieldName` style) but not to write it.

> `$val` seems to be the value of the column in the csv being imported. Is that correct?

Yes, after any formatting has been applied.

> What is contained in `$record`?

It's the source row for the record in the CSV after formatting callbacks have been run on it, provided for context.

---

I hope this helps and that you can achieve what you want to achieve! This part of the framework probably hasn't had a lot of love in recent times, so please feel free to make a pull request to improve it in any way, even if it's only documentation updates! Good luck.

Comment: Thanks for the extensive answer. I'm digging into this today. If this part of the framework hasn't been updated in a while, is it safe to say the V3 documentation, found [here](http://api.silverstripe.org/3/CsvBulkLoader.html), is fairly accurate?